# is there a library in python for DTW that creates exact same result as matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, time-series, cluster-analysis, dtw

I am trying to replicate the result of a paper related to clustering time-series data. The original code is written in Matlab and I realized that available Python libraries for calculating DTW do not produce the same result as Matlab built-in function.

I searched for the source code of Matlab, but the only thing I could find was a Wikipedia page that MathWorks refer to. after coding the algorithm on that page, I still see some differences between the result. can someone please help me with this?